# asp.net mvc 4 working as web application not as a website

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have a simple asp.net mvc 4 web application, there is no code problem or any issues with routing.

I deploy it to IIS(any version) as a web application it works fine i can browse my site fine. 
If i just deploy it to web site, it throws standard 404 not found exception.

I am trying to understand why this happens with asp.net mvc web applications?

Any clues? Any experience deploying this as a web site?

Comment: How are you deploying?

Comment: using visual studio web deploy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web Applications are compiled, Web Sites are as-is, meaning your C# files are served without actually being compiled in to a .dll

This is why it isn't working, MVC sites must be compiled in to a .dll

Comment: does that mean there is no way my application can run as website if they have compiled dlls?

Comment: The c# files inside your MVC application it's self needs to be compiled. So no, you can't run an MVC web application as a ASP.NET Web Site.